# Skip DLL files in .NET setup project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, installation

everyone, I am having a question or problem when building a setup project for an add-in (both are developed in c#). The add-in is used for a big software, and it needs a DLL from the software. If I just build the add-in and use it, it is fine. But if I install it using a setup project, the DLL provided by the software should also be copied to make the add-in work. But since if the client who uses the software, has already the DLL (coming along with the software), so I wanted to skip this DLL, so exclude it from the setup. But if I do so, I will get error 1001 when installing the add-in, saying at least one type from the assembly (the add-in) cannot be loaded. If I include everything (all the dependencies), it works.

So does anyone have idea about this? How can I skip the already available DLL that comes along with the software?

Comment: Sounds like DLL Hell to me.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot this, assuming they are all managed DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [web deployment project](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24509) to build your application instead of the default publish in visual studio and before building it right click on the WDP and select Open Project File:

inside the .wdproj file search for item group `<ItemGroup></ItemGroup>` tag and add the following

`<ExcludeFromBuild Include=”$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\FolderName\**\*.*” />`

Comment: Well actually I am not developing a web application, so I don't think the web deployment project is suitable here. But thanks for the advice anyway.